# Class defines instance member property, but extended class '(Anonymous class)' defines it as instance member function

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

I have this error:

```
 Class 'Entity' defines instance member property 'method', but extended class '(Anonymous class)' defines it as instance member function
```

My code looks like:

```
export abstract class Entity {

    abstract method: () => void

}

const e = new (class extends Entity {
    method(): void {
        return;
    }

});
```

I found this issue on github but couldn't follow the reasoning:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9722

anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well nvm, this answers my other question too:

```
export abstract class Entity {

    abstract method(): void // <--- this needs to be method not (arrow) function

}

const e = new (class extends Entity {
    method(): void {
        return;
    }

});
```